# Flatmap implementation

Tags: c++, c++11

I have an implementation of flatmap for `std::vector`. However, I find the repetition of the inferred return type to be ugly. And, in general, I suspect that the implementation could be cleaner or more general.

```
template<typename T, typename FN>
static auto flatmap(const std::vector<T> &vec, FN fn) -> std::vector<typename std::remove_reference<decltype(fn(T())[0])>::type> {
    std::vector<typename std::remove_reference<decltype(fn(T())[0])>::type> result;
    for(auto x : vec) {
        auto y = fn(x);
        for( auto v : y ) {
            result.push_back(v);
        }
    }
    return result;
};
```

It can be used like this:

```
TEST_F(MarkdownUtilTests, testFlatmap) {
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3};
    std::vector<int> result = flatmap(v, [](int x) { return std::vector<int> { x, x*2, x*3 }; } );
    assertThat(result, is(std::vector<int> {1,2,3,2,4,6,3,6,9} ));
}
```

Answer (score 6):

There's a reason the algorithms in the standard library use iterators instead of dealing with containers directly. One is that it makes code like this quite a bit simpler. For example, using iterators, we could write `Flatmap` something like this:

```
template <typename InIter, typename OutIter, typename FN>
void Flatmap(InIter begin, InIter end, OutIter out, FN fn) {
    for (; begin != end; ++begin) {
        auto y = fn(*begin);
        std::copy(std::begin(y), std::end(y), out);
    }
}
```

This is somewhat more versatile, since it can take input from/write output to essentially any iterator, rather than necessarily reading from one vector and producing another vector. Likewise, what's produced by `fn` doesn't have to be a vector either--it can be essentially any container (anything for which we can use `std::begin()` and `std::end()`, to be more exact). While vector is certainly common, there are reasons for using other containers--and sometimes even a reason to write to something that isn't exactly a container either. For example:

```
std::vector<int> inputs { 1, 2, 3 };

Flatmap(inputs.begin(), inputs.end(), 
        std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\t"), 
        [](auto x) { return std::vector<decltype(x)> { x, x * 2, x * 3 }; });
```

Note that I've used `auto` as the parameter type in the lambda, so this test code requires C++14, but `Flatmap` itself is fine with C++11.

If you wanted to be a bit more forward thinking, you could write this to work with ranges instead of iterators. [Eric Neibler's range library](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) is fairly nice, and seems well on its way toward being included in an upcoming C++ standard.

Along with the code being simpler and more versatile, the other obvious advantage would be that this follows the same style as standard library code--for example, its signature and usage is essentially identical to `std::transform`.

Comment: The advantage of not using iterators is that composition is easier. I can do a `flat_map( filter( vec, f1), f2 )` type thing which is pretty ugly to express using iterators . However the `range` based option looks like a nice way to clean some of that up.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson: Yes, ranges do compose much more nicely, while retaining most of the advantages of iterators.

Comment: Perhaps I'm just not handy enough with c++11, but what is required to implement flatmap in the range library... I've tried a bit, but guess I just dont grok it well enough yet.

Comment: These comments are diverging far enough from reviewing the existing code that I've opened a new question on stack overflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36051851/how-to-implement-flatmap-using-rangev3-ranges

Comment: The problem with this is that it doesn't compose. Flatmap of Flatmap is not possible?? You want a type signiture something like `` Flatmap = (Range<T>) (T->Range<U>) -> (Range<U>)`` ie Flatmap takes a range of element type T and a function that for every element t of the input range produces a new range of element type U which is then concatenated together produces a new range of element type U. Theoretically it should be possible in c++ to do this with a zero overhead abstraction. I've tried myself and it is not so easy. The advantage of the above solution is that it is fast.